# Gmail returning file size of 0kb

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Making an imap request to gmail in php.

Files are returning with names, but a size of 0 and no contents.

This was working  during testing, I have not changed anything from when it was working, and I feel that I may have hit some limit. I was looking into gmail API limits and the limits seem so high that I would not have hit them.

I tested using a different gmail account and was getting 0kb file size returns on every file type.

Is there a way to see what my limits are and where I am at with the google API?

[image: Downloaded Files]

Comment: it'd be odd if you hit a limit on getting filesizes. if you've hit a query limit of some sort, you should get NOTHING back, not partial results like that.

Comment: I restarted the server and was getting some sql errors. So I tried restarting the sql process and got an error "/var/lib/mysql is full". Spent 5 minutes trying to fix and just deleted the VM. Spun up a new one and it is working. They were related, but it took more time to resolve than it did to just recreate. Thanks for the input Marc B.